# Suggestion For Storing huge amount of images on server [PHP]

Tags: php, image

I am having one website for image gallery. Where i want to store Million of photographs on server. So please suggest me how i can store the images so that it will be easily retrieval and storing...

Should i go for database or Storing into Directory .. 
I will not go with database , it will panic to retrieve data. 
If  go with Directory structure , it will be problem if 1000 start operation of upload then it will be problematic..

Thanks in advance

Comment: With MILLION of images maybe you should look at Amazon S3 or something like that...

Comment: Yes , i am going to use Amazon S3 only !

Comment: Dude CDN is for storing cache ~!!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What exactly are you asking about? How to store files?

Comment: Changed my discription \

Comment: absolutely do *not* store image data in a database. It's a terrible idea.

Comment: If you have already decided to save the images on Amazon S3, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about the best way to store images on a server, I would suggest that you store the image files in a directories and save the links to those images in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Try a key value store one nice key value store is [redis](http://www.redis.io) its fast and easy to learn it will enable fast storing and retrieval of the images.